# Quotient of two convergent sequences

Tags: real-analysis

From Tao's Analysis-I:

> Let $\left(a_n\right)_{n=m}^{\infty}$ and $\left(b_n\right)_{n=m}^{\infty}$ be convergent sequences of real numbers, and let $x, y$ be the real numbers $x:=\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} a_n$ and $y:=\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} b_n$.
>
> Suppose that $y \neq 0$, and that $\color{red}{b_n \neq 0 \forall n \geq m}$. Then the sequence $\left(a_n / b_n\right)_{n=m}^{\infty}$ converges to $x / y$; in other words,
> $$
> \lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{a_n}{b_n}=\frac{\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} a_n}{\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} b_n}
> $$

Why does Tao mention the condition $b_n \neq 0$ for all $n \geq m$? Isn't it already implied when he says $y\ne0$?

Comment: $b_n \neq 0$ for $n \geq $ SOME $m$. He is fixing $m$ so that the  new sequence $\left(a_n / b_n\right)_{n=m}^{\infty}$ is defined.

Comment: @geetha290krm so what you mean is for the limit of the sequence to be defined, the sequence itself has to be defined first.

Comment: Yes, that is true.

Comment: @geetha290krm that makes a lot of sense. Thanks a ton!